# Are generics the answer to handle multiple databases?

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, generics

I've been trying to mess around with generics and get a way to handle multiple database types example: Database so the class where this will be declared will be a MongoDB database class.

How can I implement this? Are generics the answer to handler better multiple database types?

Comment: Your question is broad, but can you narrow down your use case of handling multiple databases?  The JDBC interface should cover well most relational databases.  Presumably Mongo has its own Java interface as well (though I've never used or seen it).

Comment: Ok so i'll have to handle multiple databases which i dont know the type(it can be mongo, mysql, etc), im creating a core for my minecraft network and every plugin connected to this core can have multiple databases. Example: my minigame plugin i'll have a mongodb database but my other minigame plugin i'll have a mysql database. I want to create a solid way to do this. When i refer to mongodb i refer to the Morphia(MongoDB object-document mapper) which i had to write a single class called Mongo to handle my map DAO's and everything.

Comment: JDBC is a good way to start and is pluggable. Also Java features a [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) which is, I think, a way-to-go.

Comment: @Flown im already using mongo db xD 
What i want to do is: Database<E> -> and get all the functions withing the E element. And when declare a extends Database<Mongo> i need to declare my db options which are the params to my Mongo Class

Comment: Ah ok now it's clear what you asking. How would your `Database<E>` look like?

Comment: @Flown Well thats the thing i dont know (im quite a noob using generics), for now i just need a way to connect all my database "pools" through a generic to be easier to implement and read. What i need? I need that my E  element can access all the methods within the class i'll declare has an E element and i need to have access to the E constructor

Comment: It's still kind of broad nonetheless. A SQL RDBMS and MongoDB are completely different things, and IMHO they "should" be handled differently. Yes you can have things that "emulate the wire protocol" ( i.e CosmosDB ) to make your calls work on either. But really that is going to have limitations that effectively make a sub-set of "neither" the result. At a class level, I'm generally in favor of abstraction, but again the more generic you get, the less "features" of either advantage get used.

Comment: @NeilLunn the thing is im not the only one who gonna use this core and i want to have a straight foward and clean way to pickup a type of Database and implement it just by calling a simple generic and im kinda newbie at this all generic thing so im stuck xD

Comment: @Flown is that possible with generics right ? xD

Comment: I think it's not possible in the way you want it.

Comment: @Flown theres any way to make this simple without generics? abstract class?

Comment: I think I don't understand your requirements completely, but if you want to support different DBMS you need a common interface - as @NeilLunn said, you are getting more abstract. You can't get specific behaviour dynamically, except you're using reflections and this is hard to get right.

Comment: @Flown thanks for helping me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question cannot have a right answer, because there could be many ways to achieve a good result. Generics could be a way, you can read how Spring Data created something like this from this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jdbc-generic-dao)